# Is there a way to drop all duplicates in a df and add their occurrence in a prexisting column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, duplicates

I would like to drop all duplicates within my df and add their occurrence in a prexisting column, e.g. 'four'.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': pd.Series([True, True, True, False]),
                   'two': pd.Series([True, False, False, True]),
                   'three': pd.Series([True, False, False, False]),
                   'four': pd.Series([1,1,1,1])})

     one    two  three  four
0   True   True   True      1
1   True  False  False      1
2   True  False  False      1
3  False   True  False      1
```

Should look like this:

```py
     one    two  three  four
0   True   True   True      1
1   True  False  False      2
2  False   True  False      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `sum` the aggregation function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': pd.Series([True, True, True, False]),
                   'two': pd.Series([True, False, False, True]),
                   'three': pd.Series([True, False, False, False]),
                   'four': pd.Series([1, 1, 1, 1])})

print(df.groupby(['one', 'two', 'three'], sort=False).sum().reset_index())
```

Outputs

```
     one    two  three   four
0   True   True   True      1
1   True  False  False      2
2  False   True  False      1
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for! :)